# Take screenshot programmatically with a certain scale (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, screenshot

I want to take a screenshot of a UIImageView but the problem is that I want it to be two times wider ant two times higher than the original size. Some advice?

Here's my current code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myImageView.bounds.size);
[myImageView.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();             
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Why do you want it to be 2x it's original size? That won't make the resolution any better. You can simply scale the printscreen, like any other image.

Comment: But I think I've read somewhere that there's a function for scaling the image context. If there's not, I'll do it your way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` with the scale option set to 2.